# Constant issues during multi node creation on various hosters

Tags: debian, vps, jelastic

I am creating 16-48 nodes envs on different hosters (Dogado,Mgrid,Docktera,Scaleforce) and i am running into weird issues recently.

I have been using Jelastic platform on exact same setup for almost a year now, but recently i just ran into issues when creating multinode vps enviorments.

Responses are

Either

"result": 2348,
"error": "Error occurred during installing JEM",
"source": "JEL"

or

Error occurred during create node: Can't lock cache for key [42f919c5a1d661eedda45342eba0c16b_vds_ADD_NODE]

Or

org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.hivext.api.server.system.persistence.FirewallRule#70755]; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.hivext.api.server.system.persistence.FirewallRule#70755]

Anyone got something in mind why it happens across only few Hosters, but with others the same setup works just fine??

Can't unlock cache for key [33c964806ac4cffec06031a77a4cabb4_vds]

Comment: May I ask what the 16-48 nodes are used for? Sounds like an unusual use case, especially applying across multiple providers?

Comment: This error occurs due to a previously reported bug "JE-56642
AddNode->Can't lock cache for key [xxxxxxxxxxxxx_vds_ADD_NODE]". This issue will be fixed in the Jelastic platform version 6.0-1.

Comment: The patch for JE-56642 AddNode->Can't lock cache for key [xxxxxxxxxxxxx_vds_ADD_NODE] was delivered recently, please check.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it sounds like you have hit a resource limit. 16 to 48 nodes is quite a lot. What are you looking to do with Jelastic that requires so many nodes? I've never had to use more than 4 nodes unless I am clustering.

If you can share your JPS script, I'll take a look.